# Clearing/Deleting messages in Twilios SMS Message Queues

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

We had some sort of bug that queued up the same message thousands of times, each of them is undelivered because of the spam carrier restrictions, because it was a not real number or something.

We've looked around their docs and stack overflow but can't find anything that looks relevant.

It seems like Twilio keeps trying though - over and over - so it's send out thousands of the same message and keeps queueing them. Or at the very least

How can we clear our whole SMS message queue? We're happy if we never send it again, as nothing in there is mission critical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach is a ticket to Twilio support via the Twilio Console or help@twilio.com as a P1 (with you Account SID), indicating you have an out of control process queuing up thousands of SMS messages.

They will ask that you fix the process and fail the messages in queue.